# Is there a way to distinguish whether <script> elements were present in HTML source vs loaded in via another JS script?

Tags: javascript, nodelist

If, for example, I'm using the following to get a NodeList of all scripts on a page:

```
document.querySelectorAll('script')
```

Is there a way to determine which scripts were present in the original HTML source vs those added sometime after via other scripts?

I tried comparing the info in the properties for each node/script: https://i.vgy.me/V62uwQ.png

But so far I can't find anything that distinguishes scripts present in HTML source compared to ones loaded in via another script.

I realize I can get this info via the dev tools Network tab in the initiator column, but I need to be able to separate scripts this way via JS if possible.

If I need to use something other than `document.querySelectorAll('script')` that would be completely fine too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to find out what is adding the scripts? If so, the only way I could think this could work is hardcoding IDs for each of the script elements that are added.

Comment: There's no easy built-in approach for this, but there are workarounds. (fetch the current page, or if you control the backend, change the page structure so that original script tags can be uniquely identified)

Comment: Thank you both, but unfortunately, I would need it to work on random sites for which I don't have that kind of control (to add IDs or otherwise uniquely identify script tags).

Comment: For those random sites, use the first workaround I mentioned - fetch the current page.

Comment: Are you creating a chrome plugin and need this functionality? if so there might be other workarounds. Could you explain your end goal behind this requirement?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, I think fetching the HTML of the current page is what I'll need to do.

Comment: @Eagnir I'm not creating a plugin. Just a little snippet for quick testing.

Comment: I'm thinking I'll need to fetch the HTML from the page source and get those scripts only in HTML source. Then create another list of scripts using document.querySelectorAll('script') that will also contain the scripts not in the HTML source code, and then filter out the scripts from this list that are also in the 1st list, which should give me a list of scripts not in the HTML source.

Comment: What's the use case for this? Maybe this is an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Requirement

You want to get all the script tags that are added to the DOM after the page is loaded.

It could be an external script *(link to a .js file)* or an *inline-script* but it is not part of the original html code.

### Solution

You can hook into the `document.createElement` function so that it adds a unique `data-external` attribute to all the script tags created after the initial page load.

You can than filter the returned scripts to get all the external tags.

### Assumptions

- You have to ensure the hook code below gets executed first before anything else.
- You have control of the original html page
- All external script tags are added via `document.createElement` *(There are other non-standard ways to add script, but its ignored in this solution)*

### Hook into document.createElement

```
// Overwrite the original 'createElement' function
document.createElement = function(originalCreateFunc) {
    // return a new modified function, essentially our hook function.
    return function() {
        // call the original function to get the element created
        var element = originalCreateFunc.apply(this, arguments);
        // check if the element created is of 'script' type
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === "script") {
            // if it is script, add a attribute
            element.setAttribute("data-external", "true");
        }
        // return the newly created element
        return element;
    };
}(document.createElement);
```

### Filter External Script

You can get only the external scripts via the below line.

```
// Only get the script tags with the 'data-external' property set to 'true'
document.querySelectorAll('script[data-external="true"]');
```

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out solution. However, the assumptions are not ones my circumstances will allow, so I can't use this. Appreciate it though!

Comment: Understandable, hopefully this helps someone else that lands on this page.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the HTML and all the JS, you can add something to the original HTML scripts, and not add it in the scripts added dynamically. E.g. all the HTML scripts can be:

```
<script class="html" src="..."></script>
```

Then you can test for this when looping over the scripts:

```
document.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(s => {
    if (s.classList.includes("html")) {
        // do something
    } else { 
        // do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be in control of the HTML or the JS, so I won't be able to do something like this. Thank you for the solution though!